# Cyclic Field Extensions of sum of radicals

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, cyclic-groups, galois-extensions

Given a field $K$ of characteristic 0, which contains a primitive root of order 3,
I would like to show that the extension $K(\sqrt2+3^{\frac{1}{3}})/K$ is cyclic.

My attempt was to look at the "bigger" extension $K(\sqrt2, 3^{\frac{1}{3}})/K$.
The problem is that I don't know it's size, because $\sqrt2$ might be in $K$ for example.
But I do know that it's embedded in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \ X \ \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$
by the diamond theorem.

Anyway, we still have to show that the initial extension is Galois, and we know it's enough to show its normality, but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: The bigger extension is Galois and abelian, since you show it is a subgroup of an abelian (cyclic, even) group. Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, which translates to every intermediate field being normal over the ground field (hence Galois since you're in the separable case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $K(\sqrt2)/K$ and $K(\sqrt[3]3)$ are Kummer extensions: the latter as $K$ has
a cube root of unity. The first has Galois group trivial or $C_2$ the second
has Galois group trivial or $C_3$. Those Galois groups have coprime orders,
so their compositum  $K(\sqrt2,\sqrt[3]3)$ is Galois over $K$ with group
$G=\text{Gal}(K(\sqrt2)/K)\times\text{Gal}(K(\sqrt[3]3)/K)$. In all possible cases
$G$ is cyclic.

The subfield $K(\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]3)$ is Galois with group a quotient of $G$
(by the Galois correspondence, since $G$ is Abelian). A quotient of a cyclic group
is cyclic.